# Google App Engine 1.3.1 JAR's in publicly available Maven repository?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-gae-plugin

Is anyone aware of a publicly available Maven repository that contains the Google App Engine 1.3.1 JAR's? I've been using the [maven-gae-plugin repository](http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/), but it's not updated yet. It looks like the JAR's on the central Maven repository are even older.

**EDIT:** It looks like Cletus's answer below has most of the JAR's, but not all of them. For example, the datanucleus-appengine-1.0.5.final.jar isn't available.

Comment: FYI - The Maven GAE plugin repository should have them soon based on this issue: http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=39&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Version%20Summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are now available at the maven-gae-plugin repository:

http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/

Comment: The GAE JAR's are now available in maven central: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<repository>
  <id>seasar</id>
  <url>http://maven.seasar.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: I found most of them except datanucleus-appengine-1.0.5.final.jar.